# How can I connect to a pop mailbox and use Rails to process the messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I need some way of connecting to a pop mailbox (this is read-only - I'm not sending out any emails) and then parsing the messages in the mailbox.

Is there a plugin or library for this in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do that with [Net::POP3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/pop/rdoc/classes/Net/POP3.html).